# How to set the color of my status bar without using Coordinator Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-statusbar

I am a little confused on how Coordinator Layout works. Below is the layout of my `app_bar_news_feed.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".news_feed">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_news_feed" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And this is the layout of the file that has the action and status bar the same color that includes this `app_bar_news_feed.xml` file, we can call it `originalpage.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_news_feed" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <include
                layout="@layout/nav_header_news_feed"
                android:id="@+id/navigation_header"/>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/friends_list"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"></ListView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

However, when I try to create the layout on another page, my status bar on this new page is all white while my action bar is the tint of blue I want it to be. Below is what I have on, we can call it `newpage.xml`. It doesn't include `app_bar_news_feed.xml` but I have tried to replicate some of the attributes from that file into this file like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tool:context=".CreatePost"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/create_post">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:id="@+id/create_post_appbar">

     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/create_post_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
         app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- Send button -->
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:id="@+id/send_post_button"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:text="Send"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/create_post_appbar"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <!-- Edit text for typing status. Light gray placeholder. -->

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/send_post_button"
        android:textColorHint="#d3d3d3"
        android:hint="Update your friends!"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:id="@+id/type_status"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have no idea why this is happening. The only difference I can find is the fact that the first xml file is wrapped in a `CoordinatorLayout` while the second is in a `RelativeLayout`. The Java files only set the action bar and do not set the tint of the status bar. Any ideas why this might be occurring?

Comment: Have u tried: `getWindow().setStatusbarColor()` ?

Comment: @Trivial I have seen that but I don't want my app to depend on API version 21, and if possible, if I don't have to set the status bar color in the corresponding java file for `originalpage.xml`, I don't see why I should have to be forced to set the status bar color in corresponding java file for `newpage.xml`

Comment: It seems that `newpage.xml` does not contains `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: @Trivial yah I noticed but even if I put `CoordinatorLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` there, I am still not able to set the status bar color. Furthermore, is there any reason for why `CoordinatorLayout` would set the  color of the status bar?